# Less css parent selector, walking up only two-three-x steps

Tags: css, less

Given this example:

```
<div class=component>

    <div class=top></div>
    <div class=bottom>
        <div class=bar>
              a bar is inserted here
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Less:

```
.component {

   .bar {
        position:fixed;
        left:0;
        right:0;

        // ------ If bar is included in parent bottom, then we want to add bottom:0 ----

        &.bottom {
                bottom:0;

                // This won't work, because it will result in:

                .component.bar.bottom {
                        bottom: 0
                }
        }

        // What we actually desire to have is:

        .component > .bottom > .bar {
                bottom:0;
        }

        // One way to achive this would be to allow the parent selector to walk up

        // The &(1) would be all of & minus the last one.
        // The $(0, 1) would be all of & minus all of &(1)
        &(1) > .bottom > &(0, 1) {
                bottom: 0;
        }

        // This should result in:

        .component > .bottom > .bar {

        }
    } 

}
```

Please read the inline comments in .bar() to understand the question.

A) Is there a way to do this in less already? 
B) Is this not a good feature to have?

Also, one should be able to cut off not only the end of the parent selector, but also the beggining. There are cases where elements are wrapped and the parent selector just don't work in such cases.

Comment: Just write it as `> .bottom > .bar` at the top `.component` level. Granular parent selector referencing is discussed at [#1075](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1075), but in this particular case do you really believe that `&(1) > .bottom > &(0, 1) ` (or whatever similar syntax from #1075) would be more convenient than `> .bottom > .bar`?

Comment: @seven-phases-max yes, I can do that, and I am right now. The only problem is that if you intend to give someone a method to call ( .bar() ) you do not want to force them to also declare > .bottom > .bar at the component level. All they should have to do is call .bar(). The .bar()  should really be the one taking care of everything that has to do with .bar(), and it should be able to look up to see where it's defined in order to apply other things, at any level prior.

Comment: There is also border-top, box-shadow and others that need to be applied. There are ways around it, but they are not as handy as this would be.

Comment: As for mixin to generate such styles - get use of mixin args and explicit class generation, e.g. `.@{custom-class}` and `> .bottom > .@{custom-class}`. You don't know a context where such mixin will be invoked anyway (i.e. `&(1) > .bottom > &(0, 1)` will just fail if I call it anywhere except `.class1 { .class2 { <here>` - still no too much sense). Besides, `extend` seems to be to fit the re-using use-case better.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I have another idea. What if you could define a selector while ignoring the nested nature you are being defined or called in. If in .bar() you could define some selector pattern while ignoring where you are , in order for you to be able to step out. That should be a really easy one to implement. I know, I can declare it outside of the nested logic, but that would prevent the code from living in one place. Instead, you could let nested logic define selectors ( and css for them ) without having to consider your nested position. Is this possible already?

Comment: As of now, nested less will always include your nested hierarchy, is it possbile to ignore that?

Comment: Well, no, that's the purpose of nesting. After all it's nothing but formatting nested selector identifiers. If selectors are not supposed to be nested one should not use nested rulesets and choose whatever other "group-hint" formatting (after all plain hotrizontal line comment like `// -----------------------` works just perfect to stress a connection even between plain related CSS rulesets... "Nesting for the sake of nesting is evil").

Comment: While it's true what you say, i also just demonstrated a case where nesting is not desired. Sometimes the nesting is deep enough that the other part just ends up having to be defined way out of eye scope that it just not good practise from a maintainance perspective. Although you'd argue that's what nesting is for, I'd still say that one should have the option of ignoring the nested context, if one desires. It would lead to cleaner code than using comments to try to connect pieces together. And I bet it would be a really easy add on. Basically ignore my context, and add this as if I were out.

Comment: In addition, extending or calling a method would not work if the code is separated as you mention. The suggested approach would still leave it working.

Comment: For me it looks like you think of it in a more complex way than it actually is. Here's the simplest and the most clean [code](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/a1f8c027e67365b7ca01) for `.component .bar` ruleset and here's [generic example](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/2af3f4cb78a692302120) for the corresponding `.make-bar()` mixin.

Comment: Don't get yourself into this example too much. There might be global attributes, such as lang, dir, browser attached onto the for instance html dom node, or body node, or any other parent node, which needs to be targeted, and might affect the behaviour of other things than one self. Even for one self, simply doing parentNode[someattribute=somevalue] & { } would not work, because it would target the parentNode and then & would contain the entire path, say from body ... in such circumstances it is neccessary to be able to ignore the path to one self, and let one apply the neccessary stuff.

Comment: @seven-phases-max please just add support for this, it's an easy add. Just ingore context. Trust me, it's not always desirable to include the context. Also your generic example quotes does not work for passing the selector when it's desired to do so if one wants to bypass this limitation.

Comment: You also cannot pass any selector that is not a very simple one. in your example bar works, but if you where matching against an attribute or .bar > .something > somethingels[attr=val]  it won't work. Something you just cannot apply with the current context, because it will just get in the wrong order. You cannot do :lang(ar)body > main > something. And you cannot do body > main > something :lang(ar) ... what you need to do is body:lang(ar) > main > something.

Comment: You simply repeat what's already written in #1075.

Comment: Hmm, there is a lot of content there. Could you point me to the post I should be looking at?

Comment: Well, *all* posts there are about this thing.